# Can't start iscsiadm inside rkt container on CoreOS

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, iscsi, openebs, rkt

I'm trying to start kubernetes with an iscsi plugin inside rkt on CoreOS using the [instruction here](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubelet-wrapper.html#customizing-rkt-options). The problem is the iscsi daemon can't start, so I'm getting an error and can't mount the volume to the pod.

```
iscsi_util.go:112] iscsi: failed to sendtargets to portal 156.64.48.59:3260 
    error: iscsiadm: Failed to load module tcp: No such file
iscsiadm: Could not load transport tcp.Dropping interface default.
[disk_manager.go:50] failed to attach disk 
iscsi: failed to setup
kubelet.go:1780] Unable to mount volumes for pod ...
```

I tried to mount the whole /dev/ inside the rkt container, but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a working solution I had to:

- Change RKT options to

  RKT_OPTS=--volume=iscsiadm,kind=host,source=/usr/sbin/iscsiadm --mount volume=iscsiadm,target=/usr/sbin/iscsiadm --volume=resolv,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf --mount volume=resolv,target=/etc/resolv.conf --volume=etcs,kind=host,source=/etc/iscsi/ --mount volume=etcs,target=/etc/iscsi --volume=iscsid,kind=host,source=/usr/sbin/iscsid --mount volume=iscsid,target=/usr/sbin/iscsid
- `sudo modprobe iscsi_tcp`

Initialize tcp module in advance because [it needed](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/blob/4c1f2d90ef1c73e33d9f1e4ae9c206ffe015a8f9/usr/transport.c#L196) for ascsiadm. But CoreOS loads modules "[as-needed](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/other-settings.html)" and by some reasons it doesn't work inside rkt container.

- `echo "InitiatorName=iqn.2001-12.com.mycompany:volume.openiscsi-initiator" > /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi`

At least some initiator name [is needed](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/blob/4c1f2d90ef1c73e33d9f1e4ae9c206ffe015a8f9/usr/discovery.c#L352).

I also filled [the bug](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1415) in CoreOS, maybe a better workaround exists.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like they'll add it default into CoreOS but you can add it in the ignition config.  The `iscsid-initiatorname.service` will create the name for you.

```
  "storage": {
    "files": [{
      "filesystem": "root",
      "path": "/etc/modules-load.d/iscsi_tcp.conf",
      "contents": { "source": "data:iscsi_tcp" },
      "mode": 420
    }]
  },
  "systemd": {
    "units": [{
        "enable": true,
        "name": "iscsid-initiatorname.service"
    }]
  }
```

This only works on a fresh install or fresh root disk so create the file, do `modprode iscsi_tcp`,  and do `systemctl start iscsid-initiatorname.service` if you don't want to start with clean root.

Then if you're using kubernetes just setup the volume mappings:

```
  kubelet:
    extra_args:
      feature-gates: MountPropagation=true

    extra_binds:
      - /usr/sbin/iscsiadm:/usr/sbin/iscsiadm
      - /usr/sbin/iscsid:/usr/sbin/iscsid
      - /etc/iscsi/:/etc/iscsi/
```

This got OpenEBS working on my baremetal CoreOS cluster.